# Unable to use tensorflow js

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, node-modules, tensorflow.js

I am trying to build a hand pose detector app using tensor flow on react, but for some reason, I cannot simply install the dependency. [image]

I'm trying to install the tensor flow handpose dependency via npm and import it on my project.

Comment: please check your internet connection. Please check if you are accessing the internet using any proxy server ?

Answer (score 0):

tfjs@4.4.0 is installed which conflicts with the package you are trying to install.

Try:

```
npm uninstall @tensorflow/tfjs
```

Then install a previous version of TensorFlow:

```
npm i @tensorflow/tfjs@3.21.0
```

Finally, install the package you want to install again.